# Is there a way of getting ID(s) of youtube channels linked to a user in discord.js?

Tags: youtube, discord.js

I was thinking about implementing a command that would show you some basic stats of a channel linked to your discord account. Is there a way of getting an ID of a channel linked to your discord account or no? I tried logging the user and member objects, but I can't really find it there, but there could be a different way of getting it.
Thanks.

Comment: Unless the user explicitly allows your bot to read their connections through OAauth2, no. (You can use a self-bot though, but that is against Discord's Terms of Service)

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to get linked accounts, you will have to get them to verify it with OAuth2 yourself and store the information in your database.

Discord doens't make this public.